# Documentation for kernelbase.dll Exception code 0xc06d007e

Tags: debugging, winapi, event-viewer

In my Event Viewer, I am getting an Unhandled Exception code 0xc06d007e for several .NET programs and I can't seem to find any documentation on this error. I found the WinAPI Error reference PDF but it doesn't list that error code. The faulting module is always listed as KernelBase.dll so I'm assuming this is either an incompatibility or a bug in a Windows Update, but I have no idea how to get to the bottom of this error. There are many KernelBase.dll exceptions online but so far I haven't been able to find any questions with this particular error that give any definite answer and I definitely have not found any documentation on it.

Comment: // E_DELAYLOAD_MOD_NOT_FOUND    0xc06d007e
#define E_DELAYLOAD_MOD_NOT_FOUND DELAYLOAD_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND)

Comment: This may be an exception caused by damage of kernelbase.dll or other system files. Use the [System File Checker tool](https://support.microsoft.com/zh-cn/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system) to repair missing or corrupted system files

Comment: @drake No. This is a perfectly normal event.